# Using OxyPlot in Visual Studio debugger extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oxyplot

I'm trying to use the OxyPlot library in a VS debugger extension (WPF Xaml UserControl), however, even the simplest example fails. The call to InitializeComponent in the control constructor throws the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
HResult=0x80131501
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'OxyPlot.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=75e952ba404cdbb0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source=PresentationFramework
StackTrace:
 at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
 at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
 at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
 at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
 at GraphicalDebugging.PlotWatchControl.InitializeComponent() in C:\code\git\temp\graphical-debugging\Visual_Studio_2015\GraphicalDebugging\PlotWatchControl.xaml:line 1
 at GraphicalDebugging.PlotWatchControl..ctor() in C:\code\git\temp\graphical-debugging\Visual_Studio_2015\GraphicalDebugging\PlotWatchControl.xaml.cs:line 29
 at GraphicalDebugging.PlotWatch..ctor() in C:\code\git\temp\graphical-debugging\Visual_Studio_2015\GraphicalDebugging\PlotWatch.cs:line 37
Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'OxyPlot.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=75e952ba404cdbb0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The OxyPlot assemblies are properly included in the extension deployment folder. The example applications for OxyPlot all work fine, so it seems to be related to VS debugger extension and how assemblies are resolved.

The XAML namespace declaration is:

```
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
```

whereas in some of the (XAML) examples I also see:

```
xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
```

That URL resolves to a 404, and trying to compile I get:

```
error MC3074: The tag 'PlotView' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://oxyplot.org/wpf'.
```

But, the WPF examples in the OxyPlot package use the same namespace declaration without problems ?

UPDATE: A fusion log for the problem, it is obvious that the assembly loader cannot find the OxyPlot.Wpf.dll, although the DLL is in the location of the installed VS extension (under C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\Extensions\Adam Wulkiewicz\GraphicalDebugging\0.7):

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2017-09-19 @ 08:46:44) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = OxyPlot.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=75e952ba404cdbb0
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: OxyPlot.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=75e952ba404cdbb0 | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\robi\AppData\Local\Temp\dev7ED0.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/OxyPlot.Wpf/OxyPlot.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Ideas ?

Comment: I am using the http:// way for the namespace and it works for me. Which oxyplot version are you using?

Comment: The 2.0.0-unstable1013 releases (via Nuget)

Comment: And it is 2.0.0-unstable1013 for OxyPlot.Core also

Comment: I am using the same version for OxyPlot.Wpf package(2.0.0-unstable1013) and v2015.1.708-alpha for OxyPlot.Core. Both via NuGet.

Comment: Ok, now, for some reason I don't know, both namespace declarations work. The exception is still the same though...

Comment: Have you tried adding an AssemblyResolve hook? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveAssembly);

Comment: @PalleDue, thnx! That worked like a charm, I'll add an answer below exactly how the code looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not being a .NET savvy person, I thank Palle Due for the solution idea, in the the extension package constructor I added:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

and then in the handler:

```
private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(args.Name);
}
```

and it loads up OxyPlot nicely. Phew.

Comment: I don't understand. Where should I put this code? Somewhere in the oxyplot.wpf library? Or somewhere in the program I've created?

Comment: In the program you have created.

Comment: It still doesn't work.
I put the above code in the constructor of the MainWindow class.
If I run the code now and I put a breakpoint on the "return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(args.Name);" line. 
args.Name doesn't change. The 
args.Name variable is "MyApplication.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null" each time until I get a stackoverflow.